# ngIf inside custom directive and $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to create a simple graph. When I hover over a circle, I want to see some information pop up in a tooltip. All the code for the graph is in a custom directive, and when data is loaded (I'm using scope.$watch), I draw the graph no problem.

The problem occurs with the tooltip. I want to use ng-if to only show certain things if data exists for them, but it's not working. I don't know if there's a scoping issue, but here's the code for the tooltip. Note that it's inside the scope.$watch inside the link function of the custom directive:

```
      var showPopup = function(el, data) {
        var svgPosition = $('#chart').position(),
          offsetTop = svgPosition.top,
          offsetLeft = svgPosition.left,
          circle = d3.select(el),
          top = parseInt(circle.attr('cy'), 10),
          left = parseInt(circle.attr('cx'), 10),
          r = parseInt(circle.attr('r'), 10),
          pop = d3.select('#tooltip');
        pop
          .html(
            '<div class="tooltip-wrapper">' +
              '<span class="number">' + data.week + '.</span>' +
              '<span class="person"><a href="#/person/' + data.name + '">' + data.name + '</a></span>' +
              '<ul>' +
                '<li ng-if="data.numbers">Numbers: ' + data.numbers + '</li>' +
              '</ul>' +
            '</div>'
          )
          .style('opacity', 1)
          .style('top', top + offsetTop + margin.top + 'px')
          .style('left', left + offsetLeft + margin.left + 'px');
      };
```

The li is still showing up as Numbers: undefined.
Any ideas how to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: nope, no errors. style() is a d3 thing.

Comment: I dont think ng-if will work with dynamically setting html in the link function because compile will never run for it i.e. angular never knows there's an ng-if since it's a directive. Have you tried moving this to the compile function for the directive?

Comment: I haven't. Not sure how to do that exactly. Inside the $watch, I have something that will trigger this function which is also inside $watch. How would I trigger this if showPopup and the event handler were encapsulated in different functions?

Comment: can't really help without seeing more scope . try logging `data` to console to see what it is

Comment: data is a list of 5 objects, each with name, date, and some have number.

Comment: can't use `ng-if` if data isn't scope object  BTW

Comment: oh, that would be it. the data isn't a scope object. hm, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this instead of the ng-if?

```
var html = '<div class="tooltip-wrapper">' +
  '<span class="number">' + data.week + '.</span>' +
  '<span class="person"><a href="#/person/' + data.name + '">' + data.name + '</a></span>' +
  '<ul>';

if (data.numbers) {
  html += '<li ng-if="data.numbers">Numbers: ' + data.numbers + '</li>';
}

html += '<li ng-if="data.numbers">Numbers: ' + data.numbers + '</li></ul></div>';

pop.html(html);
```

This is off the top of my head btw, I haven't tested it...

Comment: Hadn't thought about that, but you're right-- that is one workaround. I'm hoping there's a somewhat more elegant way to use angular though.

Comment: @ukejoe in your directive you could inject the $compile service and call $compile(pop.contents())(scope); where scope is the scope that contains that data, that may get you what you want. In fact looking at your code, data isn't included in the scope so it would never work, you need to say scope.data = data;

Comment: I put this at the end (before closing {}): $compile(pop.contents())(scope); and got Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Also tried just pop, no luck. pop.html() doesn't work either.

Comment: Normally these kind of operations are performed on the injected element to the directive. You could try something like: var el = angular.element(pop); to convert pop to an angular element before calling $compile and then you'd need to append that to your view or call pop.html(el.html()) or something similar

Comment: I'll give that a try. If it doesn't work, I'll post a fiddle this afternoon. Thanks.